# Vue Js Preloader wont stop displaying even when components load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, vuejs2

In my app, my preloader icon doesnt seem to go away when I click on a button which redirects to a new page. Since I am new to Vue, what could I possibly do to be able to have the icon go away once the page rerenders?

```
<template>
  <div class="page-loader" v-if="!isloaded">
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
    <div class="cube"></div>
  </div> 
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => {
      return {
        isloaded: false
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      document.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (document.readyState == "complete") { 
          this.isloaded = true;
        } 
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

the mounted seems to work initially but then after that it doesnt work once redirecting on the page?

Comment: Do you get data from API, or do you just output static data?

Comment: Data is coming from an API

Comment: So you need to show preload until the data has been fetched, right?

Comment: yes, in this case the data has been loaded but continues to spin

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the `onreadystatechange` as the `completed` ready state isn't related if the data has been fetched or not,  To stop the preloader after fetching data from API, It would use the `created` lifecycle.

Ex:

```
data() {
    return {
        isloaded: false,
        data: null,
    }
},
async created() {
     // any fetch method ( fetch or axios )
     const response = await fetch('API_URL')
     const data = await response.json()
     // set the data
     this.data = data;
     // here we ensure that data fetched, we can stop preload
     this.isloaded = true;
},
```